# HTML <pre> tag contents resizing on android

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview, ascii

I am currently working on a client-side HTML website, and I would like to add an ASCII-based logo at the top of my page. I am embedding this logo in `<pre>` tags to preserve whitespace, and it works as expected on desktop browsers. Also resizing in a desktop browser does not throw up any problems.

But when I access my website from an actual smartphone, the whitespace size seems to change and as a result, the ASCII-logo becomes unreadable. Pictures and actual code attached below.

**View on desktop:**
[image: View on desktop]

**View on Samsung S8:**
[image: View on Samsung S8]

```css
#boot-logo{
    margin: 0!important;
    width: 100vw!important;
    font-family: monospace!important;
    color: black!important;
    font-size: 1rem!important;
}
```

```html
<pre id="boot-logo">
██╗    ██╗██╗███╗   ██╗██████╗  ██████╗ ██╗    ██╗███████╗             
██║    ██║██║████╗  ██║██╔══██╗██╔═══██╗██║    ██║██╔════╝             
██║ █╗ ██║██║██╔██╗ ██║██║  ██║██║   ██║██║ █╗ ██║███████╗             
██║███╗██║██║██║╚██╗██║██║  ██║██║   ██║██║███╗██║╚════██║             
╚███╔███╔╝██║██║ ╚████║██████╔╝╚██████╔╝╚███╔███╔╝███████║             
╚══╝╚══╝ ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═══╝╚═════╝  ╚═════╝  ╚══╝╚══╝ ╚══════╝             
██████╗ ███████╗████████╗██████╗  ██████╗     ██╗   ██╗ ██╗    ██████╗ 
██╔══██╗██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝██╔══██╗██╔═══██╗    ██║   ██║███║   ██╔═████╗
██████╔╝█████╗     ██║   ██████╔╝██║   ██║    ██║   ██║╚██║   ██║██╔██║
██╔══██╗██╔══╝     ██║   ██╔══██╗██║   ██║    ╚██╗ ██╔╝ ██║   ████╔╝██║
██║  ██║███████╗   ██║   ██║  ██║╚██████╔╝     ╚████╔╝  ██║██╗╚██████╔╝
╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝   ╚═╝   ╚═╝  ╚═╝ ╚═════╝       ╚═══╝   ╚═╝╚═╝ ╚═════╝ 
</pre>
```

Can anybody tell me if there is a fix for this, or if this is just a flaw of the Android webview?

*Tested on desktop: Chrome, Firefox, Edge --> all working fine

Tested on mobile: Chrome, Firefox, Samsung browser --> all resizing whitespace*

Answer (score 2):

I've stumbled upon your question when trying to solve basically the same thing, in my case, it was a retro-dialog from the DOS era:

```html
<pre>
+-------------------------------------+  
|                                     |##
|     A message from the past...      |##
|                                     |##
+-------------------------------------+##
  #######################################

╔═════════════════════════════════════╗  
║                                     ║██
║     A message from the past...      ║██
║                                     ║██
╚═════════════════════════════════════╝██
  ███████████████████████████████████████
</pre>
```

And whilst on the desktop browser even in the mobile view, I've got exactly what I expected, Chrome, Vivaldi, and Firefox on Android rendered the second box misaligned:

[Screenshot of the example in Vivaldi on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ciode.png)

Finally, I've remembered that the way the text is rendered is that when a selected font is missing a given glyph a different font is used as a replacement for that particular character (and it was actually then when I've added the version containing only the ASCII characters to compare, which produced a nicely aligned box). I've then connected the remote DevTools to see what it will tell me about the fonts used, and the result for that example `<pre>` is:

> Droid Sans Mono—Local file(361 glyphs)
> Noto Sans Symbols—Local file(131 glyphs)

The semi-graphics frame length is 39 characters, so 78 for the top and bottom frame, 3 times 2 vertical frame symbols and 2 shadow symbols, two shadow symbols next to the bottom frame, and 39 shadow symbols beneath, giving a total count of 131. The boxes are 41x6, so given the fact that the spaces inside them are rendered in the preformatted block, a total of 491 characters to be rendered, and 491 minus 131 is 361.

So all the ASCII characters have been rendered using *Droid Sans Mono*, a monospace font. But the Unicode box-drawing characters have been rendered using a different font, extending the lines containing them. I.e. it's not the whitespace that is being resized, it's the drawing characters that are of a different size than the rest.

A possible fix is to use a monospace font that contains all the glyphs needed, e.g.:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org/face/dejavu-sans-mono" type="text/css">
<style>
pre {
  font-family: DejaVuSansMonoBold;
}
</style>
```

And the result is:

[Screenshot of the version using a downloadable font in Vivaldi on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ego6w.png)

Unfortunately, in my scenario, I consider using an external font an overkill. But maybe it will work for you.